# Pimpl-like encapsulation-oriented usage pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, rvalue-reference

I'd like to make only my implementation dependent on another header.

hdr:

```
// FDS.h

#include "MyMath.h"

union FancyDataStructure() {
    FancyDataStructure(): state(MyIdentityMat4), fanciful(0.31337) {}
    struct { MyMat4 state; float fanciful; };
    struct { 
        MyVec4 c0;
        MyVec4 c1;
        MyVec4 c2;
        MyVec4 c3;
        float fancy;
    };
}

// please pretend this has a good reason for existing
struct MyMat48() {
    MyMat48() {}
    MyMat48(const MyMat4& l, const MyMat4& r): left(l), right(r) {}
    FancyDataStructure left;
    FancyDataStructure right;
};
```

impl:

```
// FDS.cpp

#include "FDS.h"
#include "include/FlakyLib.hpp"

void init(MyMat48& instance, const FlakyLibrary::mat4& with) {
    instance.left.c2 = MyVec4(
                           with.FlakyMat4Subscript(3),
                           with.FlakyMat4Subscript(1), 
                           with.FlakyMat4Subscript(0), 
                           with.FlakyMat4Subscript(2), 
                       );
    instance.right.fancy = with.FlakyMat4Determinant();
    // This performs a crazy swizzle which demonstrates use of FlakyLib methods
}

extern std::vector<MyMat48> moreExternalState;
void doSomethingComplicatedAndFlaky() {
    FlakyLibrary::mat4& m = FlakyLibrary::Oracle::Query();
    MyMat48 newItem;
    init(newItem, m);
    moreExternalState.push_back(newItem);
}
```

So this should work and I can use `MyMat48` in blissful ignorance in, and without linking Flaky into, whatever other compilation unit I am using FDS.h from. It achieves the goal of defining this Mat48 structure in a way that does not infect its type definition with a dependency, and yet takes advantage of functionality provided by said dependency.

But it would be *Really Nice™* if I could make this less painful to construct. In particular, what feel like gymnastics involving just assigning values.

If I could have implemented `init` as a "private ctor" of `MyMat48` somehow, the code would be more expressive. In particular the 4 lines in the body of the last function really does perform a task I would want to squeeze into a single line.

I think I am missing some silver bullet here. I am really hoping that rvalue references could be used here. Somehow. Perhaps it wouldn't reduce the verbosity, but maybe it can make it more clear what is happening? I also question what really goes on with the temporary object, and how to ensure things (that should be) are moved and not copied.

Maybe I could design `init` better...

Comment: Replace init by MyMat48 makeMyMat48(const FlakyLibrary::mat4&) ?

Comment: Yeah. I have done that, it compiles. I guess that's pretty much it.